# In Minecraft, how do I change the text on a sign after I place it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometimes, I place a sign that is off by one letter. This gets really annoying after you show the world and the realize the misspelling. I am too lazy to type the whole thing again.

Comment: You should be able to do it with `/blockdata`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Three ways of doing it:

#### 1. Vanilla Minecraft (1.8-1.19) - Command Blocks

You can modify a sign's text in 1.8 using the `/blockdata` command.

Simply look for the sign you want to edit and get its co-ordinates within the world and:

```
/blockdata [X] [Y] [Z] {Text1:"Whatever you want in Line 1"}
/blockdata [X] [Y] [Z] {Text2:"Whatever you want in Line 2"}
/blockdata [X] [Y] [Z] {Text3:"Whatever you want in Line 3"}
/blockdata [X] [Y] [Z] {Text4:"Whatever you want in Line 4"}
```

All the commands will work as long as the text fits on the sign. Of course - The above examples above do not.
Remember, because this is NBT data, you can use json strings in it. See my answer in [Can you use json codes on signs in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188066/can-you-use-json-codes-on-signs-in-minecraft/188088#188088) for more details.

You'll need to compound `{}` the tag again to use json strings.
ie. `{Text1:"{text:"text",color:"blue"}"}`

*Note: Commands may need refining, ie. `~ ~-1 ~` instead of the `[X] [Y] [Z]`*

#### 2. Vanilla Minecraft (1.8-1.19) - Don't know how to use Commands

Your only option is to break the sign and type everything all over again.

#### 3. Minecraft Bukkit/Spigot/Whatever (1.7.10 or earilier) - Plugins!

There are numerous Bukkit plugins (from http://plugins.bukkit.org) that you can use.

For @Chantola said:

> Proofread your signs before you place them. This is really convenient.

Top results I found are:
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/signeditor/ - Sign Editor
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/signloc-edit/ - Sign Editor that edits [sign] at [co-ords]
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/sign-editor/ - A definite duplicate of the first one... With an extra added space... And maybe added features?

Drag these into your `/plugins` folder and restart your server. After (depending on the plugin), do the following:

**For SignEditor**: Look at your sign and type `/edit [Line] [New Text]`.
**For SignLoc-Edit**: Give your sign a name then `/sle modify [Name] [Line] [Nex Text]`
**For Essentials/EssentialsEx/EssentialsX**: Look at your sign and type `/sign set [Line] [Next Text]`

#### 4. Vanilla Minecraft (1.20 or later) - Vanilla Feature

1. [Just right click your sign.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/404582/75275)

Comment: Additionally, age-old Break 'n' Place works too :)

Comment: Hey! I was still editing.

Comment: Getting ahead of myself clearly. :)

Answer (score 7):

As of **Minecraft 1.20** (specifically, snapshot 23w12a), signs can now be edited simply by right-clicking them after they've been placed. Have fun!

[image: A screenshot of the Edit Sign Message GUI, with an empty hand do indicate that the sign is being edited after being placed.]

#### Sources

- [Let's talk about Sign Improvements! – Minecraft Feedback discussion post](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/14203475572493-Let-s-talk-about-Sign-Improvements-)
- [Minecraft Snapshot 23w12a – Minecraft.net blog post (section "Signs")](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-snapshot-23w12a)
- [Sign – Minecraft Wiki article (on minecraft.wiki)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign#Text)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the text is to break the sign and place it again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no easy solution to editing signs after they have been placed. Here are your three options:

1. Proofread your signs before you place them. This is really convenient.
2. Break the sign and place it again. Hopefully do 1. this time.
3. Install a mod for editing signs, the bukkit mod can be found here:
   http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/signeditor/